# Is there a way I can clean up the ng-class definition on my button?

Tags: angularjs

I am using:

```
    <button data-ng-repeat="question in test.testquestions"
            data-ng-class="{current: question.number == test.currentQuestion, correct: question.result == 't', incorrect: qh.result == 'f', shown: qh.result == 's', tagged: qh.tag == true}"
            data-ng-click="getDetail(qh.i, q.questionId)"
            data-ng-disabled="q.qs.i == qh.i">
```

The code works but the class definition is so long that I cannot easily see it in my editing window. 
Is there some way I can spread this on multiple lines or even do the definiton in my controller ?

Comment: I've made this the hacky way. I defined <button class="{{ generateClasses() }}"> in the template, and the generation is made in controller, but I don't recommend this, the generation runs every digest cycle so it can slow down the app. But why don't you wrap the line to the next one anywhere inside ng-class definition? :) it will work correctly

Comment: I didn't try the wrapping. So are you saying I can just leave the quote open and continue on the next line?

Comment: Then can you add this as an answer please. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap the ng-class expression on the new line, it's perfectly fine to do that

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly get it from your controller, but the result is different based on the test in the `ng-repeat`, so you need to get it from a function.  You want to avoid returning a different object every time, so you need to cache it somehow.  Here is an example using the `test.currentQuestion` assuming that it is a simple value type (like an int).

```
var classes = {};

$scope.getClasses = function(question) {
  if(!classes[question.number]) {
    classes[question.number] = {};
  }

  var result = classes[question.number];
  result.current = question.number === $scope.test.currentQuestion;
  result.correct = question.result === 't';
  result.incorrect = question.result === 'f';
  result.shown = question.result === 's';
  result.tagged = question.tag === true;

  return result;
};
```

Then, you can call it from your view:

```
data-ng-class="getClasses(test)"
```

Comment: as soon as there will be let's say 100 questions in testquestions array, the function getClasses will be called 100 times in each digest cycle and the application will be slow... it's not a very good practice to use it that way

Comment: @doodeec I'm not sure I understand why this is a problem.  As soon as there are 100 questions, that existing string expression will be evaluated 100 times per digest cycle as well.  Whether it calls a function, or does pure expression evaluation seems irrelevant.  In other words, I disagree.  I've done a lot of perf work in Angular, and calling functions in expressions has never been a bottleneck in my experience.. The raw number of bindings/expressions is what matters, and this solution doesn't increase the binding/expression count.

Comment: my thought is - if you wrap the function in ng-class, both the function and the ng-class expression gets evaluated during digest cycle - so it will run 100 times just to evaluate that it has to run 100 more times just to have the same result as the original solution within the template itself

Comment: I have been dealing with similar issue in a page, where there were two nested levels of ng-repeat, resulting in approximately 50 lines of 70 elements in each line, each of which had an function expression inside the template... and the page was excessively slow, but after removing optimizing those function calls to just static scope variables and using updating the variable within controller, the speed changed dramatically

Comment: I guess I'm confused.  The expression is evaluated either way, right?  Either it deserializes the expression and runs all of the sub-expressions inside of it, and does a dirty check on the result object, or it runs a function and does a dirty check on the result object. What am I missing?

Comment: What I have in mind is, that when you define the object in ng-class, angular has to parse it every digest to evaluate actual class attribute values... and when you use a function in top of it to generate that object in ng-class, the app has to run the function first and just then it is ready to evaluate classes... So in my opinion, in that case it runs both function and evaluation every digest, so it basically doubles the time of class evaluation. Do you see where I'm going with this?

Comment: @doodeec Since opinions don't matter when it comes to performance, I ran a test.  1000 items populated in a list with an inline class against the function above.  I measured the initial digest and the subsequent digest five times.  I threw out the the high and low values of each set and averaged the remaining 3 values.

Comment: @doodeec The results? INLINE CLASS: 317.6ms/36.6ms  FUNCTION: 318.6ms/36.6ms.  In other words, there is no perceivable difference.  That 1ms difference is well within the margin of error.  (The standard deviation was 5.4ms)  I'd be happy to send you my test code so you can try to reproduce my results.

Comment: well, so my presumptions were wrong... at least I learned something new, thanks for that :)

Comment: No problem!  Science FTW!  To be honest, this exercise helped me further hone my understanding of the $digest/$watch process as well. (BTW, I would have loved to been proven wrong... kind of)  :)  Cheers!